# How to pass net.Listener()'s FD to child process safely?

Tags: go, file-descriptor

I've been stucked with this issue for hours:

I have a main process served as a TCP server, the main process call Fork(), pass its net.Listener()'s FD to child process. Then child process can use net.Filelistener() to inherit this FD.

I have researched this issue through many open-sourced codes, also did some experiments. But unfortunately none of these solutions satisfy me for now since they are not portable, you also need many low-level jobs which are dangerous.

If there's any solution to pass net.Listener()'s FD to child process SAFELY, I'd be glad to know.

What I've tried for now:

1. Environment values, not portable, will cause chaos with many FDs, not safe since can be changed from outside.
2. Dup FD & Clear `FD_CLOEXEC` then exec/fork, portable but not supported by Go API, a `syscall.NoCloseOnExec()` change submitted to dev team was rejected since they want to keep syscall clean.
3. Set `SO_REUSEADDR` so child process can listen to port instantly, close parent's listener before that. Failed, not portable, not supported by Go API, also unsafe.
4. `exec.Command.ExtraFiles()`, have no idea how to get inherited FDs from child process, do I need a config file to save FD & names? This solution also have a bug, read exec's document for more detail.

All right guys, I've written a simple test case of this issue(with solution 4):

https://github.com/reckhou/go-fd-pass-test

Also include 2 executables on OS X & Linux. I tried Go 1.1 & Go 1.1.1 but this issue still remains.

Comment: would you mind posting some code? Esp. of the unsafe stuff you want to avoid? It would help to answer your question.

Comment: I will post my solution later but not now, since it might set a limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the listener in the ExtraFiles field of exec.Cmd.

Example of parent:

```
var l *net.TCPListener
cmd := exec.Command(...)
f, err := l.File()
cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{f}
```

Example of child:

```
l, err := net.FileListener(os.NewFile(3, "listener"))
```

You may also want to generalize this and have the child accept PROGRAMNAME_LISTENER_FD as an environment variable. Then the parent would set the environment variable to 3 before starting the child.

Comment: I think `[]*os.File{l}` should be `[]*os.File{f}`. Using environment variable is not a good idea since multiple FDs might be running. I will test this solution later.

Comment: Another issue is how can I get inherited FDs from child process? You didn't show how `3, "listener"` came. In fact, this part is very important for expandable services. This solution also has a bug: http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd Read comments above `ExtraFiles []*os.File`.

Comment: I've been tested this code and found it not working on both OS X & centOS. Sorry about that, but seems only clear FD_CLOEXEC is working for now.