# golang accept on already opened fd

Tags: go

I have a daemon that listens on a specific unix domain socket file. At some point it spawns a child which should continue listen on the same socket file without open a new one and overwriting the old one. I need a method that listen on a specific FD. In C it can be done with accept():

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass net.Listener()'s FD to child process safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193086/how-to-pass-net-listeners-fd-to-child-process-safely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`net.FileListener`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#FileListener) is used to turn a file descriptor into a `net.Listener`

```
f := os.NewFile(sockfd, "from parent")
l, err := net.FileListener(f)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```